# How do I mount another NTFS partition of an external hard drive running Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, ntfs, external-hdd, gparted, exfat

I have an external hard drive with the following partitions. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) on the same ext. hard drive and am unable to mount the NTFS partition on this drive. Could someone help please?

Here's the output of the `fdisk -l` command:

```
Disk /dev/sdf: 1000.2 GB, 1000204885504 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525167 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                              
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002e048

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1   *        2046   716802047   358400001    5  Extended
/dev/sdf2       716802048  1953519615   618358784    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdf5            2048   708788223   354393088   83  Linux
/dev/sdf6       708790272   716802047     4005888   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I have tried mounting it using the `mount` command with admin privileges as listed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB. The output is listed below:

Command: `mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdf2 /media/disk1/` Output:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdf2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdf2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

However on Windows 7 the NTFS partition of this drive mounts perfectly well.

Comment: Does it appear in `left side` of File Manager, where other disk drive and places appear? If not try to mount it with `gparted` or `Disk Utility`. May be `gparted` would not be installed, so install it by `sudo apt-get install gparted`

Comment: It shows up in the left sidebar of File Manager but it's not mounted there it's just listed. I tried to mount the drive using `gparted` as well, but the `Mount` option is not active for this partition. There's a warning as well which says: _Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this some operations may be unavailable._

Comment: If Windows mounts it ok, just try running chkdsk from Windows on that partition. That also updates Partition boot sector which is where NTFS signature is seen from Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the partition I was trying to mount wasn't a NTFS partition after all, instead it was an exFAT (Extended FAT) partition that I created and forgot during the installation of Ubuntu on my drive. So I copied all my data from this so called "NTFS" partition to another drive and reformatted the partition as NTFS using Windows. And now it works fine with Ubuntu as well.

I am sorry for wasting all you guys' time. And also wanna thank you all for trying to help me out.